# UITableView: change section header height depending on scroll offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, height

I have a plain UITableView and want to have a 'sticky' header (that stays where it is when the table gets scrolled). However, I want to change the height of the header depending on the scroll position.
That means that for example the header is originally 100px high. When you scroll the table down, the header height should decrease depending on the table view offset until it stays on a minimum height of, e.g. 50px.

Here's how it should look like:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I already build a quick prototype, but it doesn't perform well. Do you have any ideas on how to get this working and keep a smoothly scrolling table view at the same time?

Here's what I do:

Return the section header height depending on the table view offset:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    CGFloat percentage = max(0, (SCROLL_OFFSET_HEADER_SHRINK - tableView.contentOffset.y) / SCROLL_OFFSET_HEADER_SHRINK);
    int newHeight = max(MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT, min(MAX_HEADER_HEIGHT, MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT + percentage * (MAX_HEADER_HEIGHT - MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT)));
    return newHeight;
}
```

Update table view on each scroll event to make sure the header height changes: (which is a bad thing to do and causes the poor performance)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ((self.tableView.contentOffset.y > SCROLL_OFFSET_HEADER_SHRINK && 
         self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height > MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT) ||
        self.tableView.contentOffset.y < SCROLL_OFFSET_HEADER_SHRINK) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Any other way to set the section header height without having to reload the whole table would help me a lot! I'd like this to work on iOS 5+.

Comment: Basically what you wanted to do can be done quite simply. Create a simple view and add it on the top of the tableview. Create a headerview as big as the view that you want to scroll through and set it as tableHeaderView. Now, when the tableView scrolls, set the frame of your view according to the contentOffset of the tableView and that would be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @insane-36! This worked pretty well for me, although I also had to fit a 'pull-to-search' search bar on top of the sticky header. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I would add that if your going to change height of k6sandeep's simple view. Then you also need to set .userInteractionEnabled = false/NO in view that is regular viewForHeaderInSection. Otherwise you won't be able to edit rows that will be below your protruding regular HeaderView if your simple view will be shorter.

Comment: @sandeep it works except you lose scroll functionality when you try to scroll from the simple view that is on top.  I would call this a hack because it breaks the UX of what a tableview suppose to do.

Comment: It is not a hack, it used to be a way to do it when UICollectionView was not introduced. Now with UICollectionView, it is even easier. You can create your own supplementary view and then change the frame in your layout.

Comment: @Flo Could you please add the code that shows how you fixed it? Because I am facing the same issue. For me I couldn't set the minimum height for the header when scrolling. It is scrolling up fully. How can I resolve this?